# Can't get a fullscreen modal using NgbModal when passing content as a component

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap widgets and am attempting to create a full screen modal (header sticks on top, footer on bottom, and body scrolls in the middle).  I can easily do this with some simple html as outlined here:

https://www.codeply.com/go/DLPXHfEIiS/bootstrap-4-full-screen-modal

However, once I start getting more complex and want to call my own component as the content then it no longer works.  The component nests one level down from the modal-content and I believe this is what is breaking the flow.  I am attempting to follow the instructions outlined here:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component

Even in this above example you can inspect it and see the component is nested within the modal-content div.

The effect (when trying to go full screen using the method in the first link above) is that the modal, modal-dialog, and modal-contend all DO go full screen.  However, the nested component within the modal component sizes to content despite my attempts to style it to behave.

What obvious thing am I missing here?  Thanks in advance and happy Friday.

**::EDIT TO OVERRIDE LIMITATIONS IN COMMENTS::**

CSS

```
.gr-modal-full .modal-dialog {
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.gr-modal-full .modal-content {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

.TS CALLING THE COMPONENT

```
  const journalPopup = this.modalService.open(
    JournalPopupComponent,
    {windowClass: 'gr-modal-full', backdrop: false});
  journalPopup.componentInstance.journal = this.journal;
```

COMPONENT

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component( {
  selector: `
  <div class="modal-header"></div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer"></div>
`,
  templateUrl: './journal.popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./journal.popup.component.scss']
})

export class JournalPopupComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() journal: any;
  constructor(public modal: NgbActiveModal) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Right... there's a lot going on.  Here's my best to simplify it.  Styling is relatively straight forward:

.gr-modal-full .modal-dialog {
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.gr-modal-full .modal-content {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

Comment: Here is the .ts where I'm calling the component:

      const journalPopup = this.modalService.open(
        JournalPopupComponent,
        {windowClass: 'gr-modal-full', backdrop: false});
      journalPopup.componentInstance.journal = this.journal;

Comment: Here is the comp:

import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component( {
  selector: `
  <div class="modal-header"></div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer"></div>
`,
  templateUrl: './journal.popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./journal.popup.component.scss']
})

export class JournalPopupComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() journal: any;
  constructor(public modal: NgbActiveModal) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}

Comment: Perhaps there is an easier route.  Does anyone have a code sample of how to do a full screen modal when calling a component for the content.  Header should always stay on top, footer on bottom, and the body scrolls when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Have the answer by throwing away the above code and going more old-school.  I just used CSS and made the components absolute.  As long as the heights of my header and footer don't need to change (which I can control) this does the trick.

Props to John Paul Hennessy and his codepen for giving me the kick I needed at this link: https://codepen.io/yewnork/pen/Kpaqeq

```
.gr-modal-full .modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gr-modal-full .modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.gr-modal-full .modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.gr-modal-full .modal-header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  //background: #6598d9;
}

.gr-modal-full .modal-title {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.gr-modal-full .modal-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 81px;
  bottom: 61px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.gr-modal-full .modal-footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  //background: #f1f3f5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To open modal on full screen try below code. It's work fine.

**fullscreen** property is used to show modal on full screen.

You can assign these values to fullscreen property.
Type: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl' | 'xxl' | boolean

Here if the value is **md** than it will show modal on full screen in **tablet**.

[image]

In your code you can use like this.

```
const journalPopup = this.modalService.open(
JournalPopupComponent,
{fullscreen: true, backdrop: false});
```

journalPopup.componentInstance.journal = this.journal;

Result

[image]